# mysql returning correct link depending on the LEAST value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

OK this is a bit tricky but basically in my SQL statement im comparing prices between fields in each row to get the lowest value returned, now the issue is that each value has a link.

Would there be a way to return the correct link depending on the lowest value in an SQL statement?

below is my SQL statement.

```
SELECT 
   title, 
   my_value, 
   my_ink,

   LEAST(site_a_value, site_b_value, site_c_value) AS lowest_value, 

   site_a_link,
   site_b_link,
   site_c_link

   FROM STOCK
```

so for example if site_b had the lowest value I would only want site_b_link to be returned.

Comment: can u provide sample data from your database for clear understanding ?

Comment: Can you show us some sample data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT     title,
            my_value,
            my_ink,
            LEAST(site_a_value, site_b_value, site_c_value) AS lowest_value,     
            case LEAST(site_a_value, site_b_value, site_c_value)
            when site_a_value then site_a_link
            when site_b_value then site_b_link
            when site_c_value then site_c_link end AS lowest_value_link,
FROM STOCK
```

Comment: Changed a little error in last line. Just remember that in case of equal values mysql case choose the first one found.

Comment: what would adding `end` to the statement cause?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  title, my_value, my_ink,

  LEAST(site_a_value, site_b_value, site_c_value) AS lowest_value, 

  (
  CASE site_a_value = LEAST(site_a_value, site_b_value, site_c_value)
    THEN site_a_link
  ELSE CASE site_b_value = LEAST(site_a_value, site_b_value, site_c_value)
    THEN site_b_link
  ELSE
    site_c_link
  ) AS site_link

FROM STOCK
```